# How do I find gear info for my bike?

Tags: gears, identify-this-bike

I'm wanting to calculate the gear ratios for a bike my dad gave me as a gift but I can't find it listed anywhere, nevermind being able to find a manual. Based on the stickers it's a Performance Cross X100 and, from what my dad has told me, it was made sometime prior to 1999. However, after multiple searches I have only found that the first X model Performance made was the X103 for the year 1993 and no X100 model is listed.

[image: my bike]

And no, I don't want to count gear teeth by hand

Comment: There's less than a hundred teeth in total. You could have counted them and worked out the gear ratio in less time than it took to write this question.

Comment: Count the teeth on the chainrings (hint: the numbers may be stamped on the side, same for the cassette). Count the teeth of the cog(s). Divide chainring/cog. That's your ratio. Repeat for each ring and each cog. If you're an Excel user you can write a spreadsheet.

Comment: Count the teeth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the age of the bike, you can't really assume that its the original cassette, so if you really want to be certain, you will have to count the teeth on the cassette.
Looking at the picture, the Cross obviously doesn't refer to Cyclocross, and the huge inner ring on the cassette doesn't look stock for that time.

I ride thousands of miles a year, and don't know the gear ratios of any of my bikes. Is there a reason that it's important to you?

Comment: My dad recommended it to get an idea of which gear combinations are roughly the same

Comment: Wait, should I be looking up the decals on the gear that say "MegaRange 11-34T" and "Shimano HYPER GLIDE-C"?

Comment: you mean like this:
http://harriscyclery.net/product/shimano-11-34-thread-on-7-speed-freewheel-megarange-704.htm